# System.String ElementAt[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], Int32)' method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am recieving the exception mentioned in quotes below. I have tried to remove the problem alot but i am getting the exception below. I have read similiar answers to my problem in stack over flow but they don't solve my problem. I have also commented above the line where i recieve exception.

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233067   Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String
>   ElementAt[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String],
>   Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, UnaryExpression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, BinaryExpression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, DbExpression input)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source,
>   DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source,
>   DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateSet(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>          at Neon.DBHandler.registerStudentCourses(String p, List`1 coursesIdSelected) in
>   c:\Users\AbdullahABBASI\Desktop\AbbasiWebProject\Neon\Models\DBHandler.cs:line
>   246
>          at Neon.Student_RegisterCourse.registerbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\AbdullahABBASI\Desktop\AbbasiWebProject\Neon\Student_RegisterCourse.aspx.cs:line
>   51
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Code is below:

```
internal static void registerStudentCourses(string p, List<string> coursesIdSelected)
{
    AbbasiDatabaseEntities objDB = new AbbasiDatabaseEntities();
    Student objStudent = objDB.Students.Where(s => s.Id == p).FirstOrDefault();
    List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

    for (int i = 0; i<coursesIdSelected.Count; i++)
    {
        //in the line below i am getting exception mentioned above
        var course = objDB.Courses
            .Where(c => c.Id == (string)coursesIdSelected.ElementAt(i))
            .Select(s=> s)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        courses.Add(course);
    }

    objStudent.Courses = courses;    
}
```

Comment: LINQ query is converted to SQL at runtime. For this reason, .ElementAt(i) is not accessible

Comment: You are doing a `SELECT N+1` (technically this is a `SELECT N`)... in general this is an antipattern (you are doing a select in a for cycle, so there will be n separate queries executed to the db)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entity Framework can't convert `Where(c => c.Id == (string)coursesIdSelected.ElementAt(i))` to a query.

Introduce a helper variable to remove that code from your query:

```
for (int i = 0; i<coursesIdSelected.Count; i++){
    string selectedCourse = (string)coursesIdSelected.ElementAt(i);
    var course = objDB.Courses.Where(c => c.Id == selectedCourse).Select(s=> s).FirstOrDefault();
    courses.Add(course);
}
```

Or simplify the entire loop to:

```
student.Courses = db.Courses.Where(c => coursesIdSelected.Contains(c.Id.ToString()));
```

Comment: Considering `List<string> coursesIdSelected`, the `ElementAt()` could be changed to a `[]` (and then perhaps it would work directly).

Comment: Better the second one... It solves the antipattern of doing a `select` inside a `for`

Comment: Best Solution Ever Lovely abbasi Loves You